# Export the face angles corresponding to vertices in a .csv file

Tags: python, mesh, vertices, faces, geometry

How do I export all the face angles in a .csv file?

[image]

Also, how do I map them corresponding to a vertex (for irregular polyhedral)

```
   V  ->               Face Angle

x1,y1,z1  ->           (angle1,angle2,angle3)

x2,y2,z2  ->          (angle4,angle5,angle6,angle7)  
   .                .
   .                .
   .                .
```